# Why are the colors transposed in my webm thumbnails?

Tags: ffmpeg, webm

I have been using ffmpeg to generate webm files from png frames, and the webm files run ok in my video player, but the thumbnail colours appear transposed - blue replacing red, purple replacing orange, brown replacing green. I've also encountered issue uploading the webm to an image hosting site (which normally does support webms), though this might be an issue on their end.
I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Does anyone know what might be causing this, and how to fix it? Or how to check whether the webm files are ok or corrupted?

*Edit: ok, here's a side-by-side comparison of the thumbnails that appear in my file explorer - mp4 on the left and webm on the right.
Both were generated from the same set of pngs, using the same command except with the filename extension changed.

[image: screencap of thumbnails]

Specifically,

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i Panel2Humanized/frame%04d.png panel2humanskin.webm
```

and

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i Panel2Humanized/frame%04d.png panel2humanskin.mp4
```

Both look the same when opened with a video player. It looks like the mp4 thumbnail grabbed the 1st frame while the webm grabbed the last, but the colors should be the same in each. (The text-bubble in the top-left is yellow in the mp4).

*Follow-up: Apparently my WebMs are being generated in GBRP (Green-Blue-Red Planar) pixel format, the site I was trying to upload to requires YUV420P (Luma/Chroma 4:2:0 Planar) format, maybe that's the issue? I'm still not sure exactly what that means or how to fix it.

*Final follow-up: Looks like I needed to change the argument to:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i Panel2Humanized/frame%04d.png -pix_fmt yuv420p paned2humanskin.webm
```

Comment: Can you show an image of what you're seeing?

Comment: @Brad I've updated the question with a screencap